# regarding counting sort

Tags: arrays, sorting

i have a silly doubt regarding counting sort.What is the need to get the cumulative sum of all indexes to get sorted array when we can just iterate through the "count" array to reproduce the sorted array by seeing the count for that index.Does it affect the efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because typically each element will be of the form `{key,value}`, where we're sorting by `key`.  The output array needs to contain the `value`s.  You don't get them if you simply loop over the counts and regenerate the `key`s.

Comment: yeah.but the value can also be obtained without taking cumulative sums.We can iterate through counts of each ky and if it is >0 .insert the value

Comment: @gaurav: But where does the value come from?  The value comes from the input array.  So the natural thing to do is to iterate over the input array, and copy each {key,value} to the relevant location in the output array.  You can only do that if you have the cumulative sums.

Comment: got it.thanks.so it is not necessary that we start from the end of the original loop while copying?